# Getting values from select form with JQuery not working

Tags: jquery

Right now I have this code:

```
  $(".categories").change(function(){
var target = $('.categories option:selected').val();


  if(target == "Career")
      $(".subcat").css( "display","inherit" );
  else if(target == "Life Style")
      $(".subcat2").css( "display","inherit" );
  else if(target == "Do It Yourself")
      $(".subcat3").css( "display","inherit" );
  else if (target == "Other")
      $(".subcat4").css( "display","inherit" );
```

});

however when I choose whatever category it only return the value as being "Career", and not anything else, even though I select other options. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you include the HTML in your question?

Comment: Note that you can also use `this.value` instead of querying the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
var target = $(this).val();
```

instead of

```
var target = $('.categories option:selected').val();
```